# Datatable. Invalid json response

Tags: jquery, json, datatables, rest, jsonp

Estoy utilizando Datatables de jQuery para consumir unos servicios Restful que yo mismo programé.

He validado que el servicio está activo y al llamar al metodo get de mi modelo, tengo la siguiente respuesta:

```
[{"id":1,"puntoOrigen":5.0,"largo":15.0,"alto":20.0,"puertos":[],"nombre":"source1","tipoEntrada":"Interfaz"}]
```

He validado el json en [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/) y me aparece que el formato es correcto, sin embargo, cuando quiero mostrar esta data mediante Datatables, al cargar la página que deberia mostrarla tengo el error:

> DataTables warning: table id=dataTableSource - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

He revisado la documentación donde se me sugiere validar que el formato del json que recibo sea el correcto, pero segun la validacion en jsonlint, todo bien con el formato.

El archivo js con la configuración es la siguiente, ojalá alguien me pueda dar luz porque tengo varias horas perdido. Saludos!

```
// Call the dataTables jQuery plugin
$(document).ready(function() {

var table=$('#dataTableSource').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "type":"GET",
        "crossDomain": true,
        "dataType": 'jsonp',
        "url":"http://localhost:8080/test/proto/source",
        "dataSrc":"",
        "contentType": "application/json"
    },
    "columns": [
        {
            "data":"id"
        },
        {
            "data":"nombre"
        },
        {
            "data":"tipoEntrada"
        }
    ],
    rowid:"id",
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            //Boton para editar el registro
            "targets":3,
            "data":null,
            "defaultContent":"<a href='#' class='btn btn-info btn-circle btn-lg'><i class='fas fa-pen-square'></i></a>"
        },
        {
            //Boton para borrar el registro
            "targets":4,
            "data":null,
            "defaultContent":"<a href='#' class='btn btn-danger btn-circle btn-lg'><i class='fas fa-trash'></i></a>"
        }
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Se modificó el archivo JS de la siguiente manera y fue posible procesar la info recibida.

```
// Call the dataTables jQuery plugin
$(document).ready(function() {

var table=$('#dataTableSource').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "type":"GET",
        "crossDomain": true,
        "dataType": 'json',
        "url":"http://localhost:8080/test/proto/source",
        "dataSrc":"",
        "contentType": "application/jsonp"
    },
    "columns": [
        {
            "data":"id"
        },
        {
            "data":"nombre"
        },
        {
            "data":"tipoEntrada"
        }
    ],
    rowid:"id",
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            //Boton para editar el registro
            "targets":3,
            "data":null,
            "defaultContent":"<a href='#' class='btn btn-info btn-circle btn-lg'><i class='fas fa-pen-square'></i></a>"
        },
        {
            //Boton para borrar el registro
            "targets":4,
            "data":null,
            "defaultContent":"<a href='#' class='btn btn-danger btn-circle btn-lg'><i class='fas fa-trash'></i></a>"
        }
    ],
    responsive:true
});
```

});